# How to insert time and date, and the directory path in Notepad++?

Tags: date-time, path, notepad++

I just downloaded Notepad++ v 5.3.1 and I'm having two problems with the TextFX plugin:

1. I recorded a macro with *"TextFX Insert" > Date & Time* (no matter whether short or long format) and, after I run the macro, only the first number of the time appears

   For example, I ask to insert time and it says its `8:59 AM 11/27/2009`; but when I run the macro it only pastes `8:`.  How do I do to have the date inserted in the file without always needing to go to *TextFX > Insert > Date & Time*?
2. When I try to use "TextFX Insert" to add the directory name or full path, only the first letter appears. For example, `C:\data` would show up as only `C` for full paths or only `d` for the file name.

How do I resolve these bugs?

Answer (score 8):

I just assigned this to a shortcut key by going to *Settings → Shortcut Mapper → Plugin Commands → I:Date and Time → short format*

I am running version 5.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quite easily with autohotkey, with the added benefit that it'll work in all apps, not just Notepad++

Install AutoHotKey, and then save the code below as a .ahk file and run it.

```
:*:]t::
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, h:mm tt M/d/yyyy   
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
return
```

Note the double commas after CurrentDateTime are **not** a typo. 
With this script, typing **]t** will give you the date and time in the format

```
2:56 PM 10/11/2013
```

This second script will only work in Notepad++

```
:*:]f::
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll   
SendInput {Alt}e{Down 8}{Right}{Enter} 
SendInput ^v
ClipBoard:= ClipSaved 
return
```

While in Notepad++, this script

1. saves the clipboard to a variable
2. opens the edit menu
3. moves down 8 places to 'Copy to Clipboard'
4. moves right 1 to 'Current Full File path to Clipboard'
5. copies the file path to the clipboard
6. pastes the clipboard to Notepad++
7. copies the saved clipboard contents back into the clipboard

Both of these can be combined into one .ahk file, and you can set that to autoload on startup.

Answer (score 2):

The latest NotePad++ version I have is 5.5.1.

I ran the TextFX plugin and it works. Perhaps that is what you need to do, download the latest, then everything should be ok.

Comment: By the way, funny that this version is latest, the date/time textfx plugin works but the insertion of current directory/full path and filename is still not working...sorry!

Answer (score 2):

The author of Notepad++ [says](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2905908&group_id=95717&atid=612382), "Macro system cannot record plugin commands."

Comment: Almost 5 years later, still seems to be the case :(

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to  **Plugins** / **Plugin Manager** / **Show Plugin Manager**
2. Find **TextFX Characters** and install it
3. After restart go to **TextFX** / **TextFX Insert** and select date and time
   or current directoty

Comment: OP already stated that they were using TextFX Characters, they want to include the dynamic output in a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Go to: *Macro → Modify Shortcut/Macro → Plugin Commands*. Set a Hotkey for: "I:Date && Time - short format"

It works for me in Version 5.9.3.

If there is no "Modify Macro"-entry in "Macro", then you have to record at least one macro. It's not perfect, I know.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a current version, you can create a hotkey for inserting the DateTime into your Notepad++ document by:

- Opening the Settings menu, then ShortCut Mapper...
- Clicking on the "Plugin commands" tab
- Locate item "I:Date & Time - short format"  (item #188 on my version - or use long format if you prefer)
- Click on the item to highlight it then click the Modify button on the bottom of the screen
- Add your short cut - I used Ctrl-F5

Done!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this for the path:

- Edit / Copy to Clipboard / Current file path to clipboard
- Edit / Copy to Clipboard / Current file name to clipboard

Found here: [Lists of default mouse and keyboard shortcuts for Noteoad++ and some plugins](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of TextFX, use the Notepad++ Plugins Demo, which has both of those features built-in. Unlike TextFX, which has been abandoned and has no maintainer, Notepad++ Plugins Demo works with the 64-bit version of Notepad++.

In Notepad++, go to Plugins → Plugins Admin → tick the checkbox beside 'Notepad++ Plugins Demo' → click on 'Install". Once installed, you can go to Plugins → Notepad++ Plugin Demo → Date Time - Short/Long format to insert the date, and 'Current Directory' to insert the current directory.

You can also assign a keyboard shortcut for both of those functions. In Notepad++, go to Settings → Shortcut Mapper → Plugin Commands → and look for 'Date Time - Short/Long format' and 'Current Directory' (the plugin name is 'NppPluginDemo.dll'), double click on 'Date Time...' or 'Current Directory' to set a keyboard shortcut for the functions.