# Automatically insert time/date last modified into notepad++

Tags: notepad++, date-time, date-modified

How do I automatically insert the time & date last modified into a Notepad++ document? I have found a question about automatically inserting the current time, but it appears to be about a much earlier version and the upvoted answers no longer work.  Ideally I'd like not to have to remember to do this at the end of every editing session. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextFX allows you to do this manually and you can assign a keyboard shortcut for it as well. See the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/299796/how-to-insert-time-and-date-and-the-directory-path-in-notepad) for details.

[Plugin Central](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Plugin_Central) has a couple of plugins you could try for automatic date/time insertion:

- **Insertion** Version 2.1 (ANSI) by Don HO: Insertion of current file name and date & time. Auto-close the html/xml tag.
- **Log plugin** Version 1.0 (Unicode) by Nicholas Heckman: Log plugin allows Notepad++ has [*sic*] one of MS Notepad basic features : Append the date/time at the end of file after a file is opened in Notepad++, if file begins with ".LOG".

Comment: Do you know if "TextFX Characters" the same as TextFX?

Comment: Yes, it's the same TextFX plugin, whose current version seems to be 0.2.6 as per the Plugin Manager.